# Deploy jar to war guide on Glassfish?

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3, spring-boot

I get strange errors while trying to deploy example war file (from jar to war guide) on Glassfish.
In order to have a clean environment to test this I've set up a Dockerfile.

https://gist.github.com/bebud/10e8717375744018db1a#file-dockerfile
or copy this

```
# GlassFish 3.1.2 and spring boot guide jar to war deployment
#
# VERSION 0.1
# DOCKER-VERSION 1.0.0

FROM dockerfile/java


RUN apt-get update -qq
RUN apt-get install -qq maven git

WORKDIR /opt

#Downloading and unpacking GlassFish 312
RUN wget download.java.net/glassfish/3.1.2.2/release/glassfish-3.1.2.2.zip
RUN unzip glassfish-3.1.2.2.zip
RUN rm -f glassfish-3.1.2.2.zip
ENV PATH /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/bin:$PATH
RUN git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-convert-jar-to-war-maven
#Package the war file
WORKDIR /opt/gs-convert-jar-to-war-maven/complete

RUN mvn clean package

RUN cp target/gs-convert-jar-to-war-maven-0.1.0.war /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy

EXPOSE 8080 4848 8181
WORKDIR /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs
```

You can build using (example)

```
docker build -t user/glassfish312 .
```

and then start using

```
docker run -it user/glassfish312 /bin/bash
```

you need to start Glassfish domain with

```
asadmin start-domain
```

and view logfile with errors

```
less server.log
```

Here is an extract of the log I get

```
[#|2014-07-17T07:38:59.726+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WEB0172: Virtual server [server] loaded default web module []|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.127+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConf
igurer|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.138+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConf
igurer|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.150+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/DatabasePopulator ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.bo
ot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.238+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/DatabasePopulator ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.bo
ot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.284+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ Lorg/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabase; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframewo
rk.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSourceConfiguration ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.354+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ org/springframework/dao/DataAccessResourceFailureException ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.bo
ot.autoconfigure.jdbc.CommonsDataSourceConfiguration ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.357+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ Lorg/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.j
dbc.TomcatDataSourceConfiguration ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.359+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ com/mongodb/Mongo ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfigura
tion ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.605+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConf
igurer|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.608+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConf
igurer|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.609+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/DatabasePopulator ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.bo
ot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.611+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/DatabasePopulator ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.bo
ot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.612+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ Lorg/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabase; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframewo
rk.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSourceConfiguration ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.615+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ org/springframework/dao/DataAccessResourceFailureException ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.bo
ot.autoconfigure.jdbc.CommonsDataSourceConfiguration ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.617+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ Lorg/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.j
dbc.TomcatDataSourceConfiguration ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:00.618+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Class [ com/mongodb/Mongo ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfigura
tion ]|#]

[#|2014-07-17T07:39:01.963+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=40;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC1412: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Spring WebApplicationInitializer
s detected on classpath: [hello.WebInitializer@7df6054f]|#]
```

It would be great to know how to be able to deploy a spring boot application on Glassfish as it is (unfortunately) the only container we are allowed to use within the corporation.

EDIT:

The app runs in the provided Docker container. However, our deployment tool fails due to the Exceptions.
See server.log:

```
[#|2014-07-21T16:28:12.652+0200|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.org.glassfish.web.jsp|_ThreadID=89;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-47110(4);|Beginning JSP Precompile...|#]

[#|2014-07-21T16:28:12.666+0200|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.org.glassfish.web.jsp|_ThreadID=89;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-47110(4);|Finished JSP Precompile|#]

[#|2014-07-21T16:28:12.766+0200|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=89;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-47110(4);|webops-jolokia was successfully deployed in 598 milliseconds.|#]

[#|2014-07-21T16:28:20.201+0200|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=92;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-47110(5);|Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConfigurer|#]

[#|2014-07-21T16:28:20.933+0200|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=92;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-47110(5);|Error in annotation processing: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConfigurer|#]

[#|2014-07-21T16:28:20.968+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|global|_ThreadID=92;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-47110(5);|Class [ org/springframework/jdbc/support/MetaDataAccessException ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDatabaseInitializer ]|#]

[#|2014-07-21T16:28:20.992+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=92;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-47110(5);|Exception while deploying the app [example]|#]


[#|2014-07-21T16:28:20.992+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=92;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-47110(5);|sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:673)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:480)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:306)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:241)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:88)
        at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:70)
        at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Class.java:3098)
        at java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3078)
        at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:285)
        at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:195)
        at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:134)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:598)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:456)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:429)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:405)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:380)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:243)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:252)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:213)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:165)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:207)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:228)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:109)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:828)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:770)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1066)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:224)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:323)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.post(TemplateListOfResource.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:864)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:761)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1050)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:231)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
|#]

[#|2014-07-21T16:28:21.125+0200|SEVERE|oracle-glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=92;_ThreadName=admin-thread-pool-47110(5);|Exception while deploying the app [example] : sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy|#]
```

Comment: Does the app actually fail to start? Comments here seem to suggest that sometimes at least those logs are ignorable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864509/spring-boot-app-deployed-to-glassfish-is-giving-strange-results.

Comment: you are right. The app is running. Thanks.

Comment: I added new findings. Seems our deployment tool fails due to some TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.

Comment: That's normal I think. It means that glassfish is trying to load a class with annotations whose attributes refer to a class that it can't load. It really has no business loading classes from arbitrary locations like that so it's a bug (IMO).

Comment: Hi Dave. So you think it is a bug in Glassfish? Or bug in the dependencies within spring boot?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug related to Spring Boot deployment on glassfish. The fix will be in Glassfish 4.2 :(
[Glassfish JIRA Bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21265)