# Error deploying grails 3 app to glassfish server

Tags: java, grails, glassfish

I'm trying to deploy a grails 3 packaged war to a Glassfish 4.1.1 server. Initially I was using GF v. 4.1 but it has some bugs, so I decided to update, but it still gives me a error:

```
remote failure: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: void org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.Collection); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders. Please see server.log for more details.
```

Command deploy failed.

when deploying from console.

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.8.2"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.10"
    }
}

version "20161012-01"
group "mofel"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
}

grails {
    exploded = true
    plugins {
        //some local plugins already packaged
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files("lib/not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.11.jar", "lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar","lib/cfdi32.jar","lib/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar", "lib/cfdi-commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", "lib/itext-2.1.0.jar", "lib/core-renderer-r8.jar")
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.2.0.Final"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.8'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.8'
    compile 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.6.0'
    //Local Plugins

    compile "org.crsh:crsh.site:1.2.0-cr8"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3'
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2"
    runtime "org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208.jre7"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
}

assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

And the application.yml:

```
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: someuser
    password: somepassword


environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            #url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            url: jdbc:postgresql://server:port:databaseName
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:postgresql://server:port:databaseName
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED

---
---
grails:
    profile: web
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: mofel
    spring:
        transactionManagement:
            proxies: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false
# Spring Actuator Endpoints are Disabled by Default
endpoints:
    enabled: false
    jmx:
        enabled: true

---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            all: '*/*'
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
            html:
              - text/html
              - application/xhtml+xml
            js: text/javascript
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json
            multipartForm: multipart/form-data
            pdf: application/pdf
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8
    views:
        default:
            codec: html
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
            htmlcodec: xml
            codecs:
                expression: html
                scriptlets: html
                taglib: none
                staticparts: none
endpoints:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true
```

java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
(Tried with oracle JDK 1.8)

Any idea or suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not exactly the same issue, but it's the same solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As @jny pointed, only thing I was missing was to create a file called glassfish-web.xml inside src/main/webapp/WEB-INF.
The content of the file its:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
     <class-loader delegate="false"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

as pointed in:
[Unable to deploy Spring Boot App on Glassfish 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251587/unable-to-deploy-spring-boot-app-on-glassfish-4-1)