# Error deploying spring boot war on Glassfish 5.0

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, glassfish, war

I´m trying to generate a war file from spring boot app, and deploy on glassfish 5.0.

following the spring docs, and googling, the changes I did to the app are this:

1. On my Main class, modify to extends SpringBootServletInitializer:

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   @ComponentScan("com.yaat")
   @EnableSwagger
   @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.yaat"}, repositoryBaseClass=BaseRepositoryImpl.class)
   @EntityScan("com.yaat")
   public class App  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
       @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
           return application.sources(applicationClass);
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
       }
       private static Class<App> applicationClass = App.class;
       }
   ```

My pom.xml is this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.yaat</groupId>
<artifactId>RP_WS/artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>RP_WS</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- 
            <plugin> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            </plugin> 
        -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

the stacktrace on glassfish on deploy is this:

```
[2018-01-23T05:48:20.074+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686500074] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:24.870+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686504870] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ com/mysema/query/jpa/JPQLQuery ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslRepositorySupport ]]]

[2018-01-23T05:48:25.175+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505175] [levelValue: 900] [[
  AS-DEPLOYMENT-00011
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/BatchConfigurer
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1059)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1588)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1471)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.impl.ModuleScanner.getElements(ModuleScanner.java:302)
        at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:640)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:463)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:447)
        at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:340)
        at org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:421)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:207)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:378)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:254)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:232)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:276)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:134)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:377)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1621)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1471)
        ... 102 more
]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.186+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505186] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ com/samskivert/mustache/Mustache$Collector ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration ]]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.236+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505236] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ org/flywaydb/core/Flyway ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration ]]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.270+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505270] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Exception java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy encountered while processing annotaton for element class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.velocity.VelocityAutoConfiguration. Message is: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy. Ignoring annotations and proceeding.]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.298+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505298] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ Lorg/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderValidatorAutoConfiguration ]]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.334+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505334] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ liquibase/integration/spring/SpringLiquibase ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration ]]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.484+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505484] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.solr.SolrAutoConfiguration ]]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.513+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505513] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ Lgroovy/text/markup/MarkupTemplateEngine; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration$GroovyMarkupConfiguration ]]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.520+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505520] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ org/thymeleaf/resourceresolver/IResourceResolver ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration ]]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.525+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505525] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Exception java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy encountered while processing annotaton for element class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration. Message is: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy. Ignoring annotations and proceeding.]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.539+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505539] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientOptions; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration ]]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.552+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505552] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ Lorg/springframework/session/data/redis/RedisOperationsSessionRepository; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration$SessionRedisHttpConfiguration ]]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:25.559+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [global] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686505559] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Class [ Lorg/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/AccessTokenRequest; ] not found. Error while loading [ class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestOperationsConfiguration$SessionScopedConfiguration$ClientContextConfiguration ]]]
[2018-01-23T05:48:26.336+0000] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=44 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1516686506336] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WebModule[/RP_WS-17422801571741267263.0] ServletContext.log():2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath]]
```

Could somebody give me a tip about how to solve this problem?

Regards.

Comment: Why are you using Spring Boot 1.3.5? The 1.3.x line is no longer maintained. I’d update to 1.5 if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned class is org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer. 
Can't see any trace regarding Spring Batch in the pom.xml.

Comment: What means that? Should i add the dependency?

Comment: As long as you do not want to develop a Spring Batch application not. Checkout that one [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864509/spring-boot-app-deployed-to-glassfish-is-giving-strange-results)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Spring boot expert but I assume you need to build the WAR file with the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. It's very suspicious that your maven project is a WAR project because usually Spring Boot projects are JAr projects and use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to build a final WAR.

I think what happens is that your WAR doesn't contain some required Spring Boot runtime dependencies, so it's possible to compile your code but depoying it fails.

You should review a getting started guide for Spring Boot to check if you set up your project correctly and also see how to build a [Spring Boot WAR file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) The best way to start is to download a sample project from start.spring.io and compare it with yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a issue with glassfish server.Glassfish 3.1.2 and Glassfish 4.0 gives the same error while deploying the war file.

**But the below link suggest a answer to fix this issue.**

To make the WAR file deployable (people always seem to assume it will be) as well as executable, you need the embedded container to *not* be on the classpath in an external container.

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-convert-jar-to-war/issues/12

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and resolved it by the [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864509/spring-boot-app-deployed-to-glassfish-is-giving-strange-results). You need to include `metadata-complete="true"`metadata-complete="true" in your web.xml root element.